# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to pass data to UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I created a call of a UIView in which I draw a graph.   I am trying to pass it new data and have it update.

When I run the app on the simulator and click the tab in which the the controller housing the view is in, I receive this error:

*Thread 1:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)*

at the line:

```
let maxValue = graphPoints.maxElement()
```

Here is my code for the view:

```
@IBDesignable class GraphView: UIView {

var graphPoints :[Int]!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
init(graphPoints: [Int]) {
    self.graphPoints = graphPoints
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

@IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
@IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let width = rect.width
    let height = rect.height

    //set up background clipping area
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
        byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners,
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0))
    path.addClip()

    //2 - get the current context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]

    //3 - set up the color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    //4 - set up the color stops
    let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    //5 - create the gradient
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
        colors,
        colorLocations)

    //6 - draw the gradient
    var startPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    var endPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.height)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,
        gradient,
        startPoint,
        endPoint,
        .DrawsBeforeStartLocation)

    //calculate the x point

    let rightMargin:CGFloat = 40
    let leftMargin : CGFloat = 10
    let columnXPoint = { (column:Int) -> CGFloat in
        //Calculate gap between points
        let spacer = (width - rightMargin - leftMargin - 4) /
            CGFloat((self.graphPoints.count - 1))
        var x:CGFloat = CGFloat(column) * spacer
        x += leftMargin + 2
        print(x)
        return x
    }

    // calculate the y point

    let topBorder:CGFloat = 30
    let bottomBorder:CGFloat = 50
    let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
    let maxValue = graphPoints.maxElement()
    let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint:Int) -> CGFloat in
        var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(graphPoint) /
            CGFloat(maxValue!) * graphHeight
        y = graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
        print(y)
        return y
    }

    // draw the line graph

    UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

    //set up the points line
    let graphPath = UIBezierPath()
    //go to start of line
    graphPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))

    //add points for each item in the graphPoints array
    //at the correct (x, y) for the point
    for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i),
            y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
        graphPath.addLineToPoint(nextPoint)
    }

    //Create the clipping path for the graph gradient

    //1 - save the state of the context (commented out for now)
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    //2 - make a copy of the path
    let clippingPath = graphPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath

    //3 - add lines to the copied path to complete the clip area
    clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
        x: columnXPoint(graphPoints.count - 1),
        y:height))
    clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
        x:columnXPoint(0),
        y:height))
    clippingPath.closePath()

    //4 - add the clipping path to the context
    clippingPath.addClip()

    let highestYPoint = columnYPoint(maxValue!)
    startPoint = CGPoint(x:leftMargin, y: highestYPoint)
    endPoint = CGPoint(x:rightMargin, y:self.bounds.height)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, .DrawsBeforeStartLocation)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    //draw the line on top of the clipped gradient
    graphPath.lineWidth = 2.0
    graphPath.stroke()

    //Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
    for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
        var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
        point.x -= 5.0/2
        point.y -= 5.0/2

        let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
            CGRect(origin: point,
                size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
        circle.fill()
    }



    //Draw horizontal graph lines on the top of everything
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    //top line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:leftMargin, y: topBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width - rightMargin,
        y:topBorder))

    //center line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:leftMargin,
        y: graphHeight/2 + topBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - rightMargin,
        y:graphHeight/2 + topBorder))

    //bottom line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:leftMargin,
        y:height - bottomBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - rightMargin,
        y:height - bottomBorder))
    let color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
    color.setStroke()

    linePath.lineWidth = 1.0
    linePath.stroke()


}
```

And here is the code for my view controller in which I pass data to the view.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var graphView: UIView! 

var firstGraph : GraphView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

self.graphView = self.firstGraph


self.firstGraph = GraphView(graphPoints: [2240, 1983, 2171, 2017, 1842, 1992, 2347])
```

I'm new to Swift and I'm stumped on this problem after looking everywhere for an answer.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on that line and examine the pertaint variables when you hit it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the partaint variables. Do you mind elaborating?  I believe the problem is that the UIView is never being passed the data from the ViewController.  If I print(graphPoints) in the UIView it is returning nil which means its never receiving the passed data.  Also, if I were to just create an array of data at the top of the view where I call graphPoints, everything works fine.  But I can't figure out why the view is not receiving the array of data from the ViewController.